# A sentences from Friends series

Tags: meaning

I learn English from Friends series, am at the second episode of first season. I don't know how to define sentence: "**like i wasn't dreading tomorrow enough having to give it back to him"** and second sentence: "as far as my parents are concerned" -> can I define it like: "**according to my parents"**?

Comment: You haven't given the full context, so it's impossible to say whether "as far as my parents are concerned" actually means "according to my parents". The construction *as/so far as X is concerned* simply implies *only considering X* in relation to some contextually relevant situation. So *I approve of divorce so far as my parents are concerned* effectively means *I think my parents should get divorced* (even if the parents themselves have never *considered* that possibility).

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? And what effort have you made to understand it?? [how to understand **the sentence**]

Comment: ...and "like i wasn't dreading tomorrow enough having to give it back to him" again lacks context. But probably ***like I wasn't** [doing something enough]* is a slangy cut-down alternative to ***it's not like I wasn't** [doing it]* - cancelling out the "double negation", an emphatic way of saying ***I was**  [doing it **very much**]*.  In total, *I was really dreading tomorrow, when I would have to give it back to him* (dismissing the implication that some people might think I ***wasn't*** dreading it very much).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Frankly, if that were an answer, I would downvote it for an English language learner. Anyway, I am not so sure more context is required for a general explanation.

Comment: To give you context I would have to describe whole sitiuation from the movie, anyway, I know roughly what you mean.

Comment: Neither of my comments are intended to be "Answers". They're simply pointing out that ***without more context***, the question/s is/are badly posed. For all I know, OP has mistranscribed the main utterance (I'd find it much easier to imagine the context if it had been *Like i wasn't dreading tomorrow enough **without having to** give it back to him*).

Comment: @Constant: No, I ***don't*** know what you mean! For example, ***why*** does your cited character say "as far as my parents are concerned"? Do the parents know anything about what's being discussed? Or is it just something that involves (or would affect) them, even though they currently know nothing about it?

Answer (score 1):

The TV show Friends has been popular enough that it's possible to find descriptions of the episodes on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_One_with_the_Sonogram_at_the_End). I have not seen the episode and am extrapolating some of my answer.

If you post more questions like this one, you should include who makes the statement, the full statement, not just a phrase, and if possible, the statements that come before and after. All this information provides context and makes it easier for others to explain the colloquial and often slangy conversations.

"like I wasn't dreading tomorrow enough having to give it back to him"

Rachel plans to return an engagement ring to Barry. She's calling off their engagement to be married.

"having to give it back to him" is returning the ring and Barry is probably not going to take it well.

"like I wasn't dreading tomorrow enough" is more complicated. Let's make it a positive statement: "I am dreading tomorrow"

Rachel is unhappy or worried about returning the ring because Barry will be upset.

Making the statement negative and adding "like...enough" implies that something beyond the next statement ("having to give it back to him") has occurred. Maybe Barry called and said how he was looking forward to their meeting or is already making wedding plans. So Rachel is now doubly worried and upset about what may happen tomorrow.

The Wikipedia article reveals that Monica and Ross (siblings) have a meal with their parents, one of them makes the statement including "as far as my parents are concerned".

While, normally, "according to my parents" could be considered an equivalent statement, knowing the show, "as far as my parents are concerned" implies that the parents are ignorant of something (Ross is going to be a baby daddy?) or that the speaker disagrees with an opinion held by the parents. This is very speculative because we really need the full sentence.